# when distribute app, i can't found the file of microsoft.netcore.platforms. how it works?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

the file of microsoft.netcore.platforms Provides runtime information required to resolve target framework, platform, and runtime specific implementations of .NETCore packages.

**when distribute app, i can't found the file of microsoft.netcore.platforms. how it works?
it work on complie or runtime?**

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/):

> Define the platforms that your app will target.
>
> Create a `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` tag in the `<PropertyGroup>` section
>   of your `csproj` file that defines the platforms your app targets and
>   specify the runtime identifier (RID) for each platform that you
>   target. Note that you also need to add a semicolon to separate the
>   RIDs. See [Runtime IDentifier catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) for a list of runtime
>   identifiers.
>
> For example, the following `<PropertyGroup>` section indicates that
>   the app runs on `64-bit Windows 10` operating systems and the `64-bit
>   OS X Version 10.11` operating system.
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>     <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```